# For JDBC prepared statements, how are the position of variables determined when an actual value is supplied in the SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

If I have the following code, with one value supplied in the SQL statement, what would be the value of the position for GROUP? Is it 2 or 3? In other words, is the supplied value counted when determining the positions?

```
PreparedStatement st = null;
Connection conn      = DBConnection.getConnection();
String userId        = "myuser";
String group         = "mygroups";

String sql = "Insert into MY_TABLE (USER_ID, LOGIN_DATE, GROUP) values (?,SYSDATE,?)";

st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, userId);
st.setString(2, group);
```

Comment: If it isn't a `?` then it isn't a parameter, so it isn't counted as one

Comment: It is `2`. The indexes start at `1`, not `0` (which is the most confusing part). Then each placeholder has it's own index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes passed to the `setXYZ` methods refer to the number of placeholders - 1 is the first placeholder, 2 is the second, etc., regardless of where exactly they are used in the statement and what other literal parts that clause happens to have.